# Run ssh as a non-existent/virtual user

Tags: ssh, openssh

Is there a way to run `ssh` as a user that doesn't exist on the host initiating the ssh connection?

Let's say I have a remote host with an account setup and sshd running. I can ssh into that machine from using `ssh remote-user@remote-host`. If I have setup keys, ssh will use it and if no keys work, it will prompt me for the password. Let assume that password authentication is enabled.

Let's say I have a Docker image called `docker-image` with ssh and other required software installed. I can start the container and ssh without a problem. Note that the root user exists.

```bsh
hostname$ docker run -it --rm docker-image bash
container-id$ whoami
root
container-id$ ssh remote-user@remote-host
remote-user@remote-host's password:
```

If I start a container using a user that doesn't exist in the image, I can't connect to remote-host using ssh.

```bsh
hostname$ docker run -it --rm -u 1234:100 docker-image bash
container-id$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1234
container-id$ ssh remote-user@remote-host
No user exists for uid 1234
container-id$ echo $?
255
```

The error is coming from [ssh.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh.c#L660):

```cpp
    /* Get user data. */
    pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    if (!pw) {
        logit("No user exists for uid %lu", (u_long)getuid());
        exit(255);
    }
```

The error message makes sense because ssh uses sshconfig, keys, knownhosts etc. files from user's home directory but I think one would expect it to work when the user specifies different locations for those files like shown below.

```bsh
ssh -vvv -i /dev/null  -F /dev/null   \
         -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null      \
         -o PubkeyAuthentication=no  -o PreferredAuthentications=password \
         -o PasswordAuthentication=yes
    remote-user@remote-host
```

In the command above, none of the files that ssh needs (as far as I can tell) are in the user's home directory. Is there a way to run ssh in this case without having to mount host's `/etc/passwd` or mount a fake passwd file or mess with `/etc/passwd` file or creating a local user in the image? Am I overlooking any options?

How does it matter who the owner of the ssh process on the client is? Is there a good reason for forcing the local user check or is it just an implementation option that ssh developers took?

Comment: its not really clear to me why the container started at all, using a userid that is not an authorized user, but yes, all processes need to be associated with a user. that is how linux determines what actions the process is allowed to perform.

Comment: This question seems better suited for asking directly to the openssh developers. Perhaps via the public maillist.  SSH probably doesn't technically need a specific id, but before containers, it is a pretty unusual situation for anyone to try doing that.

Answer (score 1):

So I just had the same problem: I needed to run `ssh` from inside a docker container without an entry in `/etc/passwd`.

As I have no access to the host nor root access inside the container itself I just went ahead and replaced the offending code...

---

**Warning:** Security isn't a concern in my use case so I'm totally ok with messing things up as long as it works. I have no idea if this will cause security issues down the road so please proceed at your own risk. This is a quick and dirty hack to get the job done at all costs:

---

Inside `ssh.c` I replaced the call to `getpwuid(getuid())` with:

```c
/* Get user data without using getpwuid
 * to run ssh inside a docker container 
 * without a valid passwd entry for the current user
 */
struct passwd fake_user_data = {
    .pw_name = "ssh",
    .pw_passwd = "",
    .pw_uid = getuid(),
    .pw_gid = getgid(),
    .pw_gecos = "",
    .pw_dir = getenv("HOME"),
    .pw_shell = getenv("SHELL")
};

/* pw = getpwuid(getuid()); */
pw = &fake_user_data;
```

And in `misc.c` I modified `tilde_expand_filename`:

```c
path = strchr(filename, '/');
struct passwd fake_user_data = {
    .pw_dir = getenv("HOME")
};
if (path != NULL && path > filename) {          /* ~user/path */
    ...
} else if ((pw = getpwuid(uid)) == NULL) {
    /* bypass missing passwd entry...
       fatal("tilde_expand_filename: No such uid %ld", (long)uid); */

    pw = &fake_user_data;
}
```